# What is the word expressing the study of the connection between human physical appearance and human characters?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

According to Chinese or some Asian old knowledge, there is a connection between human physical appearance and human characters.

For example, a person who has high cheek bones tends to demand things such as money or wealth more than the one who has lower cheek bones.

Or, a person who has a high and straight nose tends to be more serious.

Do we have a similar study in the West?

I am not sure "**anthropology**" is the word.

I think "**anthropology**" seems too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remarkably there is a word for this exact thing!

> Physiognomy (from the Greek φύσις, 'physis', meaning "nature", and 'gnomon', meaning "judge" or "interpreter") is the practice of assessing a person's character or personality from their outer appearance—especially the face (Wikipedia)

The notion that you could infer personality from faces was popular 150 years ago, it is now mostly considered a pseudoscience.

Comment: There's also phrenology & its… erm…'logical' inverse, [Retrophrenology](https://wiki.lspace.org/Retrophrenology) ;)